# How to put many fields of django-tables2 into one?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I have a django table declared as follow :

```
class BookTable(tables.Table):
    user= tables.TemplateColumn("""{% include 'books/user.html' with user=record.created_by %}""")
    books= tables.TemplateColumn(
    """ {% if record.g_books.count %}
           <div class="panel-body">
            {% include 'books/details/detail.html' with book=record %}

           </div>
       {% else %}
             No New Books
       {% endif %}
       <div>

       </div>
            """)

    actions = tables.TemplateColumn("""{% include 'books/action.html' with book=record %}""")
```

I want to make changes on the order and some styles of fields and I want to render only one field that groups `user`, `books` and `actions` fields .

Is that possible with `django-tables2` or it's a bad way to do so ?

New with `django-tables2` , any advice is welcome

Thanks.

Comment: Based on your question, the answer is yes. But why use a table if you put all your data into one column?

Comment: The table is used in some other pages.. but in a specific page it has a different style : all the data are shown together in one column

Comment: You could just use one `TemplateColumn` of course. Not sure what your exact question is.

Comment: Thanks, as simple as that !
I don't know Why sometimes I'm complicating things !

Comment: @pietà Why don't you post your solution as an answer and share the knowledge?

Comment: ok I'll post it :) thnx